# Change mouse cursor to "stop" pointer on hover on disabled button in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want the mouse cursor to change to a "stop" pointer when I hover over the button, if it's disabled.  In case of an enabled button, the following code is working but it's not applicable to a disabled button:

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button1" Isenabled="false" />
```

**CS:**

```
Button1.MouseEnter += (s, e) => Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.No;
```

Comment: Do you not think that would lead to a great deal of surprise for the user? - normally, the cursor changing is an indication to the user that they can *do something*.

Comment: Yes, so changing the cursor to a stop pointer means that they are not allowed to perform any action on that button.

Comment: It makes my application more user friendly.

Comment: No, the general interpretation of changing the cursor to a stop pointer *on hovering a particular element* is "if you click now, *something* will stop"

Comment: @Damien: There is no "stop" cursor, as such. They're probably referring to what Windows terms "unavailable", or CSS "not-allowed", i.e. the red circle with a diagonal slash through it: ⦸. And that cursor usually is not interpreted as "something will stop when I click here", but rather "I cannot click here". Admittedly, using the cursor alone for signalling affordance on a freaking *button* that should show rather clearly whether it's disabled or not, is probably unnecessary and annoying, but I don't really see how it could be misinterpreted.

Comment: @Joey He's referring to the "No" cursor.

Comment: It's kind of a weird request. Presumably this user will have encountered the concept of a disabled button before, and somehow managed to understand that without the cursor changing on mouseover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you won't be able to trigger events with a disable control, I suggest placing a transparent rectangle over it, which will handle that for you:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" IsEnabled="False"/>
<Rectangle Opacity="0" Fill="Transparent">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsEnabled}" 
                             Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

The rectangle is collapsed when button is not enabled, so that it would allow button events to trigger.  When the button is enabled, rectangle becomes visible (with 0 opacity and transparent background) and causes No cursor to appear when moused over.

**EDIT:**

Per comments, here's a working sample (which also attempts to resolve an issue OP is having with enabled button canceling behavior):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <!-- Regular Button-->
            <Button Width="120" Height="22" Margin="5"/>

            <!--Custom Button-->
            <Grid Width="120" Height="22" Margin="5">
                <Button x:Name="Button1" IsEnabled="False"/>
                <Rectangle Opacity="0" Fill="Transparent">
                    <Rectangle.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsEnabled}" 
                             Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Rectangle.Style>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the demo:

[image]

I recommend creating a custom control using similar XAML, or, at the very least, create a template, so that you may reuse it.

Comment: But this trigger has a limitation. This trigger works untill and unless I hover to another enabled button i.e. when I hover to another enabled button then trigger stops working.

Comment: @TusharKukreti Hmm, let me test it, just a minute.

Comment: @TusharKukreti Works fine.  See my edit with test code and a demo.

Comment: @B.K.For above edited code: Suppose for button(name: button1) which is enabled, i'm using    button1.MouseEnter += (s, e) => Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.hand;    in CS code, and then i run my app and then i hover to enabled button it becomes hand  and then after i hover again to my disabled button then also trigger stops working

Comment: can i apply this logic to TabControls as well?

Comment: @TusharKukreti Yes to the TabControl question.  As far as your code-behind stuff.  I don't know, I didn't test that sort of thing, because I rarely define UI behavior in the code-behind -- that is what XAML is for.  The only time when I do that is perhaps in custom controls... but in a very limited scope, since most of the behavior is easily defined in XAML.

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform any operation on disabled objects.